# how to aggregate one record multiple times based on condition

Tags: sql, hive, presto

I have a bunch of records in the table below.

```
product_id       produced_date    expired_date
123              2010-02-01       2012-05-31
234              2013-03-01       2014-08-04
345              2012-05-01       2018-02-25

...              ...             ...
```

I want the output to display how many unexpired products currently we have at the monthly level.  (Say, if a product expires on August 04, we still count it in August stock)

```
Month             n_products
2010-02-01        10
2010-03-01        12

...
2022-07-01        25
2022-08-01        15
```

How should I do this in Presto or Hive?  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use below SQL.
Here we are using `case when` to check if a product is expired or not(`produced_date  >= expired_date` ), if its expired, we are summing it to get count of product that has been expired. And then group that data over expiry month.

```
select 
TRUNC(expired_date, 'MM') expired_month,
SUM( case when produced_date >= expired_date then 1 else 0 end) n_products
from mytable
group by 1
```

Comment: I would suggest using `count_if` instead of `sum-case` cause it is more readable.

Comment: Agree, i understand. I am from SQL background so i used case when( kind of universal if-else). Agree, you can use `if()` - its similar to case when.

Answer (score 0):

We can use unnest and sequence functions to create a derived table; Joining our table with this derived table, should give us the desired result.

```
    Select m.month,count(product_id) as n_products
    (Select 
    (select x
    from unnest(sequence(Min(month(produced_date)), Max(month(expired_date)), Interval '1' month)) t(x)
    ) as month
    from table) m
    left join table t on m.month >= t.produced_date and m.month <= t.expired_date
    
    group by 1 
    order by 1
```